# How to hide tab bar in the connected segue in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a problem in that I want to disable the Tab Bar in the connected view of Master View only Master View show the Tab bar but when I connected via show segue then it shows a blank tabbar. I tried to select the none in the Attribute Inspector (Bottom bar => None) but it doesn't work.

Here is the more helping screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

when you prepare for segue, write the following code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "..." {
        //VC should have the tab bar
        VC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```

Comment: still showing ... i added before the prepare for segue ! but they still showing :(

Comment: and on that tab bar that also not select-able on the more apps view that's also wiered :(

Comment: I had tested it. It worked on my Xcode. Could you post more code about this problem?

Comment: sir its not working i tried and verified couple of times

Comment: check if hide tab bar on right view controller...hide bar should not be so trouble

Comment: tried but right view should not be hidden i do this programmatically but not working ! i just make that tabbar on the storyboard

Comment: I think you have tab bar controller, and master-detail view controller, you would like to show tab bar on master, and hide on detail, am i right? I write this segue from master to detail, use "self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true", and It worked. The tab bar hidden on the detail view.

Comment: i already implemented before asking the question here ! "self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true" in every where viewDidLoad and also tried before the segue but nothing works really wiered !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the segue type on the storyboard? If you change it to modal or popup it will hide the tab bar.

Comment: show detail and show is only working present modally and present as popover works but they also hide my navigation bar so that's a big problem i don't want to hide the navigation bar on tabbar !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboard to connect different TabBar items then create a segue but choose "**relationship**" segue instead of the "**show**" segue. The relationship segue is going to add the TabBar item to the other controllers.